# Using FlexVolume on local kubernetes cluster with docker-desktop

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-desktop

I'm trying to use flex volumes for mounting file server and key vault, respectively:
[Git Repo](https://github.com/Azure/kubernetes-volume-drivers/tree/master/flexvolume/smb)
and [Git Repo](https://github.com/Azure/kubernetes-keyvault-flexvol)

However, mounting any of them cause pods needing them to get stuck in ContainerCreating with warning messages about being unable to mount volumes due to a timeout. There is a step in the configuration of non-aks clusters that requires adjusting configs, which seems to be impossible when using a docker-provided Kubernetes server.

Is it possible to install flex volume driver on the docker Kubernetes server, as outlined here [config kubelet service to enable FlexVolume driver](https://github.com/Azure/kubernetes-volume-drivers/blob/master/flexvolume/README.md#config-kubelet-service-to-enable-flexvolume-driver) and if so, how to access the config files? And if not, is it at all possible to mount flex volume volumes when working locally using docker-desktop Kubernetes?

I've deployed the same configuration to the AKS cluster and it's working correctly.

Comment: What is exactly the "docker-provided kubernetes server"? Please give some link to that. What do you mean by "that requires adjusting configs, which seems to be impossible"? Why is it impossible? What have you tried to do? What was the error message?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/kubernetes/ , quoting: 
> Docker Desktop includes a standalone Kubernetes server and client, as well as Docker CLI integration. The Kubernetes server runs locally within your Docker instance, is not configurable, and is a single-node cluster.

Comment: Also regarding the impossible, the actions to configure are outlined in the last link, however due to docker desktop k8s server not being configurable it seems to be impossible to do those adjustments

Comment: I was able to get the flexvolume for Azure KeyVault into the Docker Desktop k8s cluster.  But the pod is not starting. Opened an issue https://github.com/Azure/kubernetes-keyvault-flexvol/issues/198